# SF Package Install Warn - @salesforce/plugin-packaging different from the version specific by sf - Type Error - this.config.plugins.filter is not a fn

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli, install, app-install, sf-v2-cli

I am running into an issue/error when I am trying to run the `sf package install` command

I am using the latest `@salesforce/cli` which is currently `2.20.6` (even tried latest nightly `2.22.1`)

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/cli?activeTab=versions

It is my only package in my `package.json`, and I ensured I `npm i`

- With a clean `node_modules` folder
- Deleted the old `package-lock.json` file
- Emptied my npm cache with

  - `npm cache clean --force`

I am able to run SF commands like `sf org create`, `sf org list` and `sf org open` without issue

When I attempt to run the `sf package install` sf command I get the following warning and my Salesforce APEX package never installs

> Warning: Plugin @salesforce/plugin-packaging (1.16.6) differs from the version specified by sf (1.27.3)
> TypeError: this.config.plugins.filter is not a function

I am wondering if this is a known issue or if there is a workaround?

The full command I am running is

`sf package install --target-org scratchOrg --wait 5 --package %npm_package_config_devPackageId%`

This worked before but in newer version this seems to be an issue.

I will attempt to downgrade version of `@salesforce/cli` in effort to find a stable version for this

- Version `2.12.9` is the last GA stable release of the `@salesforce/cli` where the `sf package install` command worked
- Version `2.13.9` is the GA stable release of the `@salesforce/cli`  which introduces the issue with `sf package install` command

Thanks in advanced for your time and knowledge

[image: SF - @salesforce/cli - SF Package Install Broken]

Changelog for `@salesforce/cli` for reference

- https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/README.md

Comment: Did you try manually updating the plugin? This happens to me all the time. `sf plugins install packaging`. Yes it should update itself but I'm finding many times it doesnt. The other fix is [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399035/sfdx-create-package-version-throws-plugin-packaging-error).

Comment: @ddeve Yes I have tried manually updating to the Latest GA and the Latest Nightly and the same issue persists

I found that the command works as expected when I have installed version `2.12.9` of `@salessforce/cli` though with version `2.13.9` onwards the problem exists.

The related fix is for another issue, similar but not the same, though I do appreciate your feedback/input, fingers crossed it gets fixed in future releases.

As a workaround I just MANUALLY install the SF APEX package via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command: sf plugins reset

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208677)